# how to move billing address before payment method list using CSS magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I tried too much in vender but don't able to change the position of billing address on payment page.

I copied vender/magento/module_checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment.html
file and putted at my module

company/module/view/frontend/web/template/payment.html

```
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('beforeMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-methods-list') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
```

afterMethod put before payment-method-load but no luck

can anyone help me!

Comment: I tried working well as per my requirement

Comment: If you wish to proactively provide information to the community it still needs to be in the form of a question. Please edit to be a question and then provide an answer. In a few days time you'll be able to select that answer as accepted (or maybe someone else will have a better answer).

Comment: Richard i am new for here please help me correct it i want to be a part of stackoverflow and share my self finding.let me know where i am wrong in this post

Answer (score 4):

Add css to your style this will help you

```
    #co-payment-form .fieldset {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .checkout-billing-address {
         flex:1;
         order: 1;
    }

    .opc-payment {
        flex:1;
        order: 2;
        }

    .opc-payment-additional {
        flex:1;
        order: 3;
    }
```

After doing these changes run deploy command using cli 
flush cache

Happy Coding!

Comment: Check the link bro, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/move-billing-address-before-the-payment-method-checkout-magento/